# PHP / REST API: Splitting a string into three variables

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split a string from Formstack's RestAPI into three variables and I'm not sure how to format the syntax for the division.

Need to turn:

```
$NameVar = "first = Stacy last = Lassy middle = M";
```

Into:

```
$FirstNameVar = "Stacy";
$MiddleNameVar = "M";
$LastNameVar = "Lassy";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like [this](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xsps797x)

```
$NameVar = "first = Stacy last = Lassy middle = M";

$vars = getVariableArrays($NameVar);

foreach($vars as $key => $var){
    ${ucfirst($key) . 'NameVar'} = $var;
}

echo 'First Name: '. $FirstNameVar .'<br>';
echo 'Middle Name: '. $MiddleNameVar .'<br>';
echo 'Last Name: '. $LastNameVar .'<br>';

function getVariableArrays($NameVar){
  $NameVar = str_replace(' = ', ',', $NameVar);
  
  $strArr  = explode(' ', $NameVar);
  $nameVarArr = [];
  
  foreach($strArr as $str){
    $strVar = explode(',' , $str);
    $nameVarArr[$strVar[0]] = $strVar[1];
  }
  return $nameVarArr;
}
```